# Expandable Navigation Drawer is not moving

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am very new to action bar sherlock and navigation drawer. I have created a simple navigation drawer. The drawer is open by default whenever the app starts, and there is no way to hide the drawer after interacting with it. **What should I do, if I want the user to open the navigation drawer when he clicks the top left corner of the screen and it should hide itself if the user selects as option inside it, or again clicks the top left app icon on the screen?**

The **MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ExpandableListView mDrawerList;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);



            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // Listview Group click listener
            mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Listview Group expanded listener
            mDrawerList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Listview Group collasped listener
            mDrawerList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            // Listview on child click listener
            mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " : "
                                    + listDataChild.get(
                                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding header data
        listDataHeader.add("Today");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> today = new ArrayList<String>();
        today.add("Tanushree Guha");
        today.add("Prasenjit Roy");
        today.add("Pan Singh Tomar");
        today.add("Milka Singh");
        today.add("Rohit Ramanujan");
        today.add("Ramesh Bhatt");
        today.add("Debjani Brahma");

        listDataHeader.add("Tomorrow");
        List<String> tomorrow = new ArrayList<String>();
        tomorrow.add("Dipanjan Bhowmik");
        tomorrow.add("Sarmistha Sinha");
        tomorrow.add("Pranay Lalwani");
        tomorrow.add("Mohit Shaw");
        tomorrow.add("Lovelace Agarwal");
        tomorrow.add("Tanmay Banerjee");

        listDataHeader.add("Later");
        List<String> later = new ArrayList<String>();
        later.add("Yusuf Khan");
        later.add("Jitendar Sharma");
        later.add("Debashree Roy");
        later.add("Mainak Ghosh");
        later.add("Olivia Gomes");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), today); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), tomorrow);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), later);
    }

}
```

The **ExpandableListAdapter** class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

The **main layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

     <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#999999"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The **list_group.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#CC7A00">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The **list_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#FFCC80">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" 
        android:textColor="#336699"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The **output**:

[image: Non expanded]

[image: Expanded]

Please suggest me ways to hide the navigation bar.

You just need to copy paste the codes in a new project if you wanna see the outputs.

Comment: top button means that its the blue button you refer to ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the layout to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

 <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#999999"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in order to make it work on the menu icon, you could refer to the source code [here](https://github.com/hearbeathorror/Navigation-Drawer-With-ActionBar/)

Code snippets:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFrameHoldingList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFrameHoldingList);
        }else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFrameHoldingList);
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

mFrameHoldingList in your case will be the expandable listview

**EDIT:**
for the button click , if your app has an action bar then

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ExpandableListView mDrawerList;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private ActionBar mActionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ->> Add these lines
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

**EDIT: to make the child selectable **

```
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The menu icon onclick is not working, but if it is slided from  left to right then the menu is opening

Comment: if its an action bar then add these to the onCreate 'mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);'
'mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);'

Comment: mActionBar object could not be recognized, please show it in my existing code if possible

Comment: does your app have an action bar ?

Comment: while creating the project I chose Holo light with Dark action bar....other than that I did not do anything. As I am a novice, can you please tell me whether that was enough.or what should I do

Comment: edited the answer, make the changes now to your Activity, then add the onOptionsItemSelected code

Comment: Cheers mate! Its done, thanks a tonne. By the way, onclick list items, the navigation pane is not hiding and what should I do if I want to open corresponding activities or fragments when the user clicks on a list item and the state of the list is saved with the clicked option highlighted even after going to the next activity?

Comment: in the onclick call mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawer) method

Comment: and what about the state of the drawer

Comment: i think you could set the selection of the listview and also create a custom selector for the same such that it remains, if not you might wish to store it in a shared preference and then set the state. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and help.

Comment: the group expansion is possible but not the child selection

Comment: try setting the textViews focusable to false and also focusable in touch mode for the same in the child layout.

Comment: iv edited the answer, change true to false in the method `isChildSelectable`

Comment: can you please give me some code suggestions. Right now multiple children of a particular group could be selected by the user. I also want a group to be expanded and child selected by default. Please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705903/expandable-listview-default-selection